# Erro no if do php, sistema de autenticação de login

Tags: php, mysql, login, if

Olá, então, estou tentando fazer um simples sistema de login com php e mysql, porém ta dando erro no meu if. Já mexi... demais e nada, quando parece q da certo ele não autentica vc coloca qualquer senha q ou nome de login e vai. 
Esse aqui é o meu código:

```
<?php 
$login = $_POST['nomel'];
 $senha = $_POST['senha'];


 include 'conexao.php';

 $busca = mysql_query("SELECT * from usuario where nm_login = '$login'");

 $reg = mysql_fetch_assoc($busca);

 if 
    ($login == $reg ['nm_login']) && ($senha == $reg ['nm_senha']) {
    # code...
    header("location: test.html");
 }
 else{
    echo "<center><b>Login Incorreto!</center>";
 }
 ?>
```

E esse aqui é a mensagem de erro:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND) in E:\IMPORTANTE\USBWebserver v8.6\root\NK\autenticacaoLogin.php on line 13*

Comment: Nessa postagem, você encontra um sistema de cadastro e login feito usando PDO do PHP, tá bem explicado.
http://maclaine.meximas.com/post/post.php?id=40

Answer (score 3):

Faltou uns parêntesis no `if` que tem no código, este:

```
if ($login == $reg ['nm_login']) && ($senha == $reg ['nm_senha']) {
```

Tem um parêntesis para cada comparação do `if` mas não tem um que englobe toda a comparação.

[Veja um exemplo simplificado do erro no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Wa2LoH)

Pode então fazer assim:

```
if (($login == $reg ['nm_login']) && ($senha == $reg ['nm_senha'])) {
//-^--------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Ou simplificar e utilizar apenas um parêntesis para o `if` todo:

```
if ($login == $reg ['nm_login'] && $senha == $reg ['nm_senha']) {
```

---

Aconselho vivamente a atualizar as funções de banco de dados para mysqli uma vez que as versões mysql foram descontinuadas e não existem mais a partir da versão 7 do php.

Deve também considerar tratar o input recebido no `$login` e `$senha` ou utilizar *prepared statements*, porque como tem o código no momento está susceptível a ataques de *mysql injection*

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que o código é mais para fins didáticos, se como disse o colega acima, ele está sijeito a ataques não só de SQL Injection.
Mas para a comparação, use a busca no SQL já retornando somente o usuário que tenha LOGIN E SENHA já validados.

```
$busca = mysql_query("SELECT * from usuario where nm_login = '$login' and nm_senha='$senha'");
```

depois só verifique se a consulta retornou algum resultado ou vazio....